# Strange rectangular bald patches when rendering hair particles as a grass object

Tags: particles, hair

So I'm setting up a scene that involves a hill in the background and I am using the hair particle system to cover it in a grass model I made.

In viewport, it seems to be working as intended. The grass is spread evenly across the area where I want it to go and avoiding the sand, which I have controlled with weight painting.
[image: Viewport, lookdev mode.]

But, when I render the scene, there's this area where it seems like the grass is only appearing along the edges of the mesh, rather than the whole face.
[image: Cycles render]

I don't think it's the subdivision surface modifier, because I have both the viewport and render divisions set to the same value.

[image: Modifier stack]

I'm going to cover the hill with trees so it might not be too noticeable in the end, but I would love to find out what's causing this weird effect.

[.blend Dropbox link because blend-exchange wasn't working](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g6kihcc4qvng7k0/Grass%20Hill%20Problem.blend?dl=0)